# How are folks automating Windows server (DNS server) if chef cant survive reboots?

Tags: chef-infra

It's hard to get any answers around windows automation... So, to keep it simple... How are we automating Windows server deployments these days if chef fails after initiating a reboot?

Comment: This is quite a broad question. We are using Chef on Windows and have a few work-arounds for rebooting and can help if you limit your question a little to what part of the bootstrap / process you are having issues with?

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to get people to answer windows automation questions and no one ever does... so this was just another attempt. Basically, while setting up and configuring a domain on windows server 2016, I have to schedule a reboot once it's finished, then once the server is back up the chef run should ideally continue configuring windows server... but the issue is that the reboot seems to interrupt the chef run.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this through Test Kitchen or bootstrapping an actual server? We have machines joining domains and handling the Chef reboot / exit scenario.

Comment: I am doing this through test kitchen using winrm on a vagrant virtual machine using virtual box vm.